# Remove starting point from dotted arrows in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, tikz-arrows

I want to remove the starting 'heads' from the dotted arrows I drew from coordinates to nodes. With `to` instead of `edge` they dont appear but I cant get them dotted. Any ideas?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\newcommand{\mym}{\mkern-1.5mu-\mkern-3mu 1}    % small minus for subscripts

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[   cnode/.style={draw=black,fill=#1,minimum width=3mm,circle},
]
    % draw 3 timesteps
    \foreach \x in {1,...,3}
    {   
        % nodes input hidden and output
        \node[cnode=blue,label=180:$ x_{\x}$] (x-\x) at ({3.3*\x-div(\x,4)},0) {};
        \node[cnode=gray,label=90:$ v^{(1)}_{\x}$] (p-\x) at ({3.3*\x-div(\x,4)},2) {};
        \node[cnode=orange,label=90:$ r^{(1)}_{\x}$] (q-\x) at ({3.3*\x-div(\x,4)},4) {};
        \node[cnode=gray,label=90:$ v^{(2)}_{\x}$] (r-\x) at ({3.3*\x-div(\x,4)},6) {};
        \node[cnode=orange,label=90:$~~r^{(n\mym)}_{\x}$] (h-\x) at ({3.3*\x-div(\x,4)},8) {};
        \node[cnode=gray,label=90:$ v^{(n\mym)}_{\x}~$] (g-\x) at ({3.3*\x-div(\x,4)},10) {};
        \node[cnode=red, label=90:$ x^{(n)}_{\x}$] (s-\x) at ({3.3*\x-div(\x,4)},13) {};
        % cords for nowhere arrows
        \coordinate[left of=r-\x] (n-\x);
        \coordinate[right of=h-\x] (m-\x);
        \draw [->](q-\x) edge [dotted, bend left=30] (n-\x); 
        \draw [->](m-\x) edge [dotted, bend right=30] (g-\x); 
        % draw weights
        \draw [->](x-\x) to [bend right=45] node[right,pos=0.6] {$ \omega_v^{(1)}$} (p-\x);    
        \draw [->](x-\x) to [bend left=45] node[left,pos=0.7] {$ \omega_r^{(1)}$} (q-\x);          
        \draw [->](p-\x) to [bend right=45] node[right,pos=0.75] {$ \omega_v^{(2)}$} (r-\x);            
        \draw [->](h-\x) to [bend left=45] node[left,pos=0.7] {$ \omega_r^{(n)}$} (s-\x);
        \draw [->](g-\x) to [bend right=45] node[right,pos=0.7] {$ \omega_v^{(n)}$} (s-\x);   
        \node at ({3.3*\x-div(\x,4)},7.4) {$\vdots$};
    }
    % add last input \tau
    \node[cnode=blue,label=180:$ x_{\tau}$] (x-4) at (14,0) {};
    \node[cnode=gray,label=90:$ v^{(1)}_{\tau}$] (p-4) at (14,2) {};
    \node[cnode=orange,label=90:$ r^{(1)}_{\tau}$] (q-4) at (14,4) {};
    \node[cnode=gray,label=90:$ v^{(2)}_{\tau}$] (r-4) at (14,6) {};
    \node[cnode=orange,label=90:$~~r^{(n\mym)}_{\tau}$] (h-4) at (14,8) {};
    \node[cnode=gray,label=90:$ v^{(n\mym)}_{\tau}~$] (g-4) at (14,10) {};
    \node[cnode=red, label=90:$ x^{(n)}_{\tau}$] (s-4) at (14,13) {};
    \draw [->](x-4) to [bend right=45] node[right,pos=0.6] {$ \omega_v^{(1)}$} (p-4);        
    \draw [->](x-4) to [bend left=45] node[left,pos=0.7] {$ \omega_r^{(1)}$} (q-4);        
    \draw [->](p-4) to [bend right=45] node[right,pos=0.75] {$ \omega_v^{(2)}$} (r-4);
    \draw [->](h-4) to [bend left=45] node[left,pos=0.7] {$ \omega_r^{(n)}$} (s-4);    
    \draw [->](g-4) to [bend right=45] node[right,pos=0.7] {$ \omega_v^{(n)}$} (s-4);  
    \node at (12,2) {$\cdots$};
    \node at (12,4) {$\cdots$};
    \node at (12,6) {$\cdots$};
    \node at (12,8) {$\cdots$};
    \node at (12,10) {$\cdots$};
    \node at (14,7.4) {$\vdots$};   
   % draw recurrent weights
    \foreach[evaluate=\x as \xnext using int(\x+1)] \x in {1,2}
    {
        \draw [->](p-\x) -- node[above,pos=0.4] {$ \nu_v^{(1)}$} (p-\xnext);   
        \draw [<-](q-\x) -- node[above,pos=0.55] {$ \nu_r^{(1)}$} (q-\xnext);  
        \draw [->](r-\x) -- node[above,pos=0.4] {$ \nu_v^{(2)}$} (r-\xnext);   
        \draw [->](h-\x) -- node[above,pos=0.55] {$ \nu_r^{(n\mym)}$} (h-\xnext); 
        \draw [<-](g-\x) -- node[above,pos=0.4] {$ \nu_v^{(n\mym)}$} (g-\xnext);     
    }
    % dotted arrows for last timestep
    \coordinate[left of=r-4] (n-4);
    \coordinate[right of=h-4] (m-4);
    \draw [->](q-4) edge [dotted, bend left=30] (n-4); 
    \draw [->](m-4) edge [dotted, bend right=30] (g-4); 

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT:**
Additional Question: how to move the starting points of those arrows slightly upwards or downwards?

With @SchrödingersCat s Hint that was possible by using two coordinates for each starting point like this:

```
\coordinate[left= 0.8 of r-\x] (N-\x);
\coordinate[right= 0.8 of h-\x] (M-\x);
\coordinate[above= 0.3 of N-\x] (n-\x);
\coordinate[below= 0.3 of M-\x] (m-\x);
\draw (q-\x) edge [dotted, bend left=30, ->] (n-\x); 
\draw (m-\x) edge [dotted, bend right=30, ->] (g-\x);
```

Comment: Put the arrow in the edges: `\draw q-4) edge [dotted, bend left=30,->] (n-4);` instead of `\draw [->](q-4) edge [dotted, bend left=30] (n-4); `. Explanation: an edge starts a new path so technically you draw two paths, hence the excess arrow hear. Alternatively you can say `\draw [dotted, ->](q-4)  to[bend left=30] (n-4);`.

Comment: perfect, thank you thats it! Sometimes tikz can be simple. May I ask you how you know that? Or better is there any good literature / documentary on Tikz where could look such things up?

Comment: also do you happen to know, how to move the \coordinates slighlty upwards/downwards from where they are?

Comment: Which coordinates should be moved where?

Comment: the  \coordinate[left of=r-\x] (n-\x); from the first loop should be moved slightly higher from where they are now and  \coordinate[right of=h-\x] (m-\x); on the other hand slightly lower

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An edge starts a separate path. So if say

```
 \draw [->](q-4) edge [dotted, bend left=30] (n-4);
```

Ti*k*Z sees two paths, one is just the point `(q-4)`, and the other one is the edge, and the arrow head gets applied to both. There are two ways you can solve this: either replace the above by

```
 \draw q-4) edge [dotted, bend left=30,->] (n-4);
```

i.e. move the arrow to the edge, or replace `edge` by `to`

```
 \draw [dotted, ->](q-4) to[bend left=30] (n-4);
```

As you see, you need also to move `dotted` to the options of `\draw` in that case.

I personally am not a big fan of `edge`s, nor or `quotes`, so I'd go for the second option. (Why am I not a fan? This is because paths can be used for intersections, recycled with `save path` and `use path` etc, but with `edges` this is more complicated.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\newcommand{\mym}{\mkern-1.5mu-\mkern-3mu 1}    % small minus for subscripts

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[   cnode/.style={draw=black,fill=#1,minimum width=3mm,circle},
]
    % draw 3 timesteps
    \foreach \x in {1,...,3}
    {   
        % nodes input hidden and output
        \node[cnode=blue,label=180:$ x_{\x}$] (x-\x) at ({3.3*\x-div(\x,4)},0) {};
        \node[cnode=gray,label=90:$ v^{(1)}_{\x}$] (p-\x) at ({3.3*\x-div(\x,4)},2) {};
        \node[cnode=orange,label=90:$ r^{(1)}_{\x}$] (q-\x) at ({3.3*\x-div(\x,4)},4) {};
        \node[cnode=gray,label=90:$ v^{(2)}_{\x}$] (r-\x) at ({3.3*\x-div(\x,4)},6) {};
        \node[cnode=orange,label=90:$~~r^{(n\mym)}_{\x}$] (h-\x) at ({3.3*\x-div(\x,4)},8) {};
        \node[cnode=gray,label=90:$ v^{(n\mym)}_{\x}~$] (g-\x) at ({3.3*\x-div(\x,4)},10) {};
        \node[cnode=red, label=90:$ x^{(n)}_{\x}$] (s-\x) at ({3.3*\x-div(\x,4)},13) {};
        % cords for nowhere arrows
        \coordinate[left of=r-\x] (n-\x);
        \coordinate[right of=h-\x] (m-\x);
        \draw [dotted,->](q-\x) to[bend left=30] (n-\x); 
        \draw [dotted,->](m-\x) to[bend right=30] (g-\x); 
        % draw weights
        \draw [->](x-\x) to [bend right=45] node[right,pos=0.6] {$ \omega_v^{(1)}$} (p-\x);    
        \draw [->](x-\x) to [bend left=45] node[left,pos=0.7] {$ \omega_r^{(1)}$} (q-\x);          
        \draw [->](p-\x) to [bend right=45] node[right,pos=0.75] {$ \omega_v^{(2)}$} (r-\x);            
        \draw [->](h-\x) to [bend left=45] node[left,pos=0.7] {$ \omega_r^{(n)}$} (s-\x);
        \draw [->](g-\x) to [bend right=45] node[right,pos=0.7] {$ \omega_v^{(n)}$} (s-\x);   
        \node at ({3.3*\x-div(\x,4)},7.4) {$\vdots$};
    }
    % add last input \tau
    \node[cnode=blue,label=180:$ x_{\tau}$] (x-4) at (14,0) {};
    \node[cnode=gray,label=90:$ v^{(1)}_{\tau}$] (p-4) at (14,2) {};
    \node[cnode=orange,label=90:$ r^{(1)}_{\tau}$] (q-4) at (14,4) {};
    \node[cnode=gray,label=90:$ v^{(2)}_{\tau}$] (r-4) at (14,6) {};
    \node[cnode=orange,label=90:$~~r^{(n\mym)}_{\tau}$] (h-4) at (14,8) {};
    \node[cnode=gray,label=90:$ v^{(n\mym)}_{\tau}~$] (g-4) at (14,10) {};
    \node[cnode=red, label=90:$ x^{(n)}_{\tau}$] (s-4) at (14,13) {};
    \draw [->](x-4) to [bend right=45] node[right,pos=0.6] {$ \omega_v^{(1)}$} (p-4);        
    \draw [->](x-4) to [bend left=45] node[left,pos=0.7] {$ \omega_r^{(1)}$} (q-4);        
    \draw [->](p-4) to [bend right=45] node[right,pos=0.75] {$ \omega_v^{(2)}$} (r-4);
    \draw [->](h-4) to [bend left=45] node[left,pos=0.7] {$ \omega_r^{(n)}$} (s-4);    
    \draw [->](g-4) to [bend right=45] node[right,pos=0.7] {$ \omega_v^{(n)}$} (s-4);  
    \node at (12,2) {$\cdots$};
    \node at (12,4) {$\cdots$};
    \node at (12,6) {$\cdots$};
    \node at (12,8) {$\cdots$};
    \node at (12,10) {$\cdots$};
    \node at (14,7.4) {$\vdots$};   
   % draw recurrent weights
    \foreach[evaluate=\x as \xnext using int(\x+1)] \x in {1,2}
    {
        \draw [->](p-\x) -- node[above,pos=0.4] {$ \nu_v^{(1)}$} (p-\xnext);   
        \draw [<-](q-\x) -- node[above,pos=0.55] {$ \nu_r^{(1)}$} (q-\xnext);  
        \draw [->](r-\x) -- node[above,pos=0.4] {$ \nu_v^{(2)}$} (r-\xnext);   
        \draw [->](h-\x) -- node[above,pos=0.55] {$ \nu_r^{(n\mym)}$} (h-\xnext); 
        \draw [<-](g-\x) -- node[above,pos=0.4] {$ \nu_v^{(n\mym)}$} (g-\xnext);     
    }
    % dotted arrows for last timestep
    \coordinate[left of=r-4] (n-4);
    \coordinate[right of=h-4] (m-4);
    \draw [dotted,->](q-4) to[ bend left=30] (n-4); 
    \draw [dotted,->](m-4) to[ bend right=30] (g-4); 

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Where is that all documented? In the `pgfmanual`. It is, of course, true that the `pgfmanual` is not very short, so you can ask questions here or just browse through the question. Your question has already been asked, e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/241497/194703), but I admit it is only easy to find if you already know the answer. If someone wants to close this as a duplicate, I will be happy to remove this post.

Comment: thanks a lot again! Yeah I figured somebody already stumpled over this issue, but I couldnt find the right formulation to actually find that issue here.
Besides that do you happen to know how I could move the \coordinates slightly upwards/downwards?

Comment: @Quastiat Which coordinates do you want to move, and where? The main issue is that you are using the deprecated positioning mechanisms. You might want to load the `positioning` library, in which case `\coordinate[left of=r-\x] (n-\x);` would get replaced by `\coordinate[left=<distance> of r-\x] (n-\x);`. where the position of `of` has moved and you can specify the distance. (You can also specify the node distances globally with `node distance=<y distance> and <x distance>` of just `node distance=<universal distance>`.)

Comment: Alright thank you i will try the first approach with an added ´above=<distance> of´

Comment: Alright so apparently its not possible to combine two of those `left=<dist> of` arguments right? then I could only use the explicit coordinates I guess. 
I dont really get your remark in brackets, does that mean I should declare `node distance = (-1,-1)` and then use `left=node distance of (h-0)`?

Comment: @Quastiat It is hard for me to see what you have tried. How about you append the code to your question that it is clear what you are referring to?

Comment: Sorry yeah you're right, but I already figured a workaround, I will append it to my question :)

Answer (score 2):

I quote the TikZ 3.1.4b manual pages 253-254

> The **edge** operation works like a **to** operation that is added after the
>   main path has been drawn, much like a node is added after the main
>   path has been drawn. This allows each **edge** to have a different
>   appearance. As the node operation, an **edge** temporarily suspends the
>   construction of the current path and a new path p is constructed. This
>   new path p will be drawn after the main path has been drawn. Note that
>   p can be totally different from the main path with respect to its
>   options.

So, it is enough to replace the operation `\draw` by the operation `\path` which will ultimately only trace the path once. It is well built twice, but it is traced only once.

```
% replace draw by path
        \path [->,blue](m-\x) edge [dotted, bend right=30] (g-\x);
```

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\newcommand{\mym}{\mkern-1.5mu-\mkern-3mu 1}    % small minus for subscripts

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[   cnode/.style={draw=black,fill=#1,minimum width=3mm,circle},
]
    % draw 3 timesteps
    \foreach \x in {1,...,3}
    {   
        % nodes input hidden and output
        \node[cnode=blue,label=180:$ x_{\x}$] (x-\x) at ({3.3*\x-div(\x,4)},0) {};
        \node[cnode=gray,label=90:$ v^{(1)}_{\x}$] (p-\x) at ({3.3*\x-div(\x,4)},2) {};
        \node[cnode=orange,label=90:$ r^{(1)}_{\x}$] (q-\x) at ({3.3*\x-div(\x,4)},4) {};
        \node[cnode=gray,label=90:$ v^{(2)}_{\x}$] (r-\x) at ({3.3*\x-div(\x,4)},6) {};
        \node[cnode=orange,label=90:$~~r^{(n\mym)}_{\x}$] (h-\x) at ({3.3*\x-div(\x,4)},8) {};
        \node[cnode=gray,label=90:$ v^{(n\mym)}_{\x}~$] (g-\x) at ({3.3*\x-div(\x,4)},10) {};
        \node[cnode=red, label=90:$ x^{(n)}_{\x}$] (s-\x) at ({3.3*\x-div(\x,4)},13) {};
        % cords for nowhere arrows
        \coordinate[left of=r-\x] (n-\x);
        \coordinate[right of=h-\x] (m-\x);
        \draw [->](q-\x) edge [dotted, bend left=30] (n-\x); 

        % replace draw by path
        \path [->,blue](m-\x) edge [dotted, bend right=30] (g-\x); 
        % draw weights
        \draw [->](x-\x) to [bend right=45] node[right,pos=0.6] {$ \omega_v^{(1)}$} (p-\x);    
        \draw [->](x-\x) to [bend left=45] node[left,pos=0.7] {$ \omega_r^{(1)}$} (q-\x);          
        \draw [->](p-\x) to [bend right=45] node[right,pos=0.75] {$ \omega_v^{(2)}$} (r-\x);            
        \draw [->](h-\x) to [bend left=45] node[left,pos=0.7] {$ \omega_r^{(n)}$} (s-\x);
        \draw [->](g-\x) to [bend right=45] node[right,pos=0.7] {$ \omega_v^{(n)}$} (s-\x);   
        \node at ({3.3*\x-div(\x,4)},7.4) {$\vdots$};
    }
    % add last input \tau
    \node[cnode=blue,label=180:$ x_{\tau}$] (x-4) at (14,0) {};
    \node[cnode=gray,label=90:$ v^{(1)}_{\tau}$] (p-4) at (14,2) {};
    \node[cnode=orange,label=90:$ r^{(1)}_{\tau}$] (q-4) at (14,4) {};
    \node[cnode=gray,label=90:$ v^{(2)}_{\tau}$] (r-4) at (14,6) {};
    \node[cnode=orange,label=90:$~~r^{(n\mym)}_{\tau}$] (h-4) at (14,8) {};
    \node[cnode=gray,label=90:$ v^{(n\mym)}_{\tau}~$] (g-4) at (14,10) {};
    \node[cnode=red, label=90:$ x^{(n)}_{\tau}$] (s-4) at (14,13) {};
    \draw [->](x-4) to [bend right=45] node[right,pos=0.6] {$ \omega_v^{(1)}$} (p-4);        
    \draw [->](x-4) to [bend left=45] node[left,pos=0.7] {$ \omega_r^{(1)}$} (q-4);        
    \draw [->](p-4) to [bend right=45] node[right,pos=0.75] {$ \omega_v^{(2)}$} (r-4);
    \draw [->](h-4) to [bend left=45] node[left,pos=0.7] {$ \omega_r^{(n)}$} (s-4);    
    \draw [->](g-4) to [bend right=45] node[right,pos=0.7] {$ \omega_v^{(n)}$} (s-4);  
    \node at (12,2) {$\cdots$};
    \node at (12,4) {$\cdots$};
    \node at (12,6) {$\cdots$};
    \node at (12,8) {$\cdots$};
    \node at (12,10) {$\cdots$};
    \node at (14,7.4) {$\vdots$};   
   % draw recurrent weights
    \foreach[evaluate=\x as \xnext using int(\x+1)] \x in {1,2}
    {
        \draw [->](p-\x) -- node[above,pos=0.4] {$ \nu_v^{(1)}$} (p-\xnext);   
        \draw [<-](q-\x) -- node[above,pos=0.55] {$ \nu_r^{(1)}$} (q-\xnext);  
        \draw [->](r-\x) -- node[above,pos=0.4] {$ \nu_v^{(2)}$} (r-\xnext);   
        \draw [->](h-\x) -- node[above,pos=0.55] {$ \nu_r^{(n\mym)}$} (h-\xnext); 
        \draw [<-](g-\x) -- node[above,pos=0.4] {$ \nu_v^{(n\mym)}$} (g-\xnext);     
    }
    % dotted arrows for last timestep
    \coordinate[left of=r-4] (n-4);
    \coordinate[right of=h-4] (m-4);
    \draw [->](q-4) edge [dotted, bend left=30] (n-4); 
    % replace draw by path
    \path [->](m-4) edge [dotted, bend right=30] (g-4); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you that works as well!

Comment: @Quastiat There is another way to do the same : add the `tips=proper` option to the `tikzpicture` environment: `\begin{tikzpicture}
[cnode/.style={draw=black,fill=#1,minimum width=3mm,circle},tips=proper]`

Comment: @AndréC Always very good in particular with tikz-pgf.